# Unwanted left margin/padding to logo in toolbar

Tags: android, layout, toolbar, android-toolbar

[This is my application toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDzke.png)

I have added menu button and logo in following manner.

```
final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_parking);
```

I have tried doling following in toolbar xml but it did not help.

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```

What I want to do is to get my logo close to menu button and apply some padding to it.

**Update**
Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root_login_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml

Comment: try to set title with an empty string getSupportActionBar().setTitle(");

Comment: title is appearing to the right side of logo, so I dint think that is the problem

Comment: check with another image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml seems correct there is not issue in code it might be problem with your image so replace it with proper image you can definitely check with image editor like gimp,photoshop there will be a inner padding inside your ic_parking image which you are set as toolbar logo.

you can check with replace it with another image which does not have any inner padding in image itself hope you understand what exactly i'm trying to say.

Regards.

Comment: Hmm fine this is common problem of image you can check your image in image editor tool it contains inner margin inside image itself. :)